# Motion expressed by equations

Tags: kinematics

**$y=u(t-k)+\frac{1}{2}a(t-k)^2$ and $y=ut+\frac{1}{2}at^2$ are two equations depicting motions of a body.**

**Q.How the motions depicted by these two equations are different?**

---

> [image]*The graph of $y=u(x-k)+\frac{1}{2}a(x-k)^2$  for $k=2s$ and $a=10ms^2$ and $u=5.8 ms^{-1}$*
>
> [image]*The graph of  equation:$y=ux+\frac{1}{2}ax^2$ for $k=2s$ and $a=10ms^2$ and $u=5.8 ms^{-1}$*

These both graphs look pretty parallel and same,except the first one is shifted version of 2nd one.

---

Again,

> *(From 1st equation)*$$y=ut-uk+\frac{1}{2}at^2+ak^2-2atk$$
> $$\frac{\text{d}y}{\text{d}t}=u+2at-2ak$$
>
> $$y''=2a$$

Here the acceleration and velocity of the 1st equation are different from the 2nd equation.

---

For my part,I think that the in the $1$st equation the motion started when $t=2$ and in the $2$nd equation motion started from $t=0$.That is the only difference.But the mathematics shows that the have *different accelerations*,which is independent of time variable.(provided I assume the accelerations to be constant).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Itachi, perhaps your calculations should be corrected as follows:

> *(From the 1st equation)*$$y=ut-uk+\frac{1}{2}at^2+\frac{1}{2}ak^2-atk$$
> $$\frac{\text{d}y}{\text{d}t}=u+at-ak$$
>
> $$y''=a$$
>
> *(From the 2nd equation)*$$y=ut+\frac{1}{2}at^2$$
> $$\frac{\text{d}y}{\text{d}t}=u+at$$
>
> $$y''=a$$

Comment: @Itachí Uchiha Is it OK?

Answer (score -1):

Your interpretation is correct. Only difference in the two cases is one is starting two seconds later.

One of the ways to write the equation is $$y= u(t-t_0)+\frac{1}{2} a (t-t_0)^2$$ In first case, say for $y1(t)$, $t_0=2$, while for second case, for $y2(t)$, $t_0=0$. Since $u$ and $a$ are same for both the cases, their initial velocities and acceleration are same. That is what you are getting, $y''= a$.

However, any quantity that depends on time will be shifted by $t_0$ for case 1. We can see that by writing it explicitly. For case 1, 
$$\frac{dy1}{dt}= u+ 2a(t-t_0)$$
while for case 2, it is
$$\frac{dy2}{dt}=u+2a(t-0)=u+2at$$

Comment: um..Is not Accelaration of case 2 is supposed to be a?

Comment: Yes. Its a in both cases.